# Ubuntu 16.04.1 opens to small window under VMWare

Tags: vmware-player, vmware-workstation

I've installed Xenial 16.04.3 under VMWare Workstation Player 14 (current version). Unfortunately, Ubuntu opens in a small window. I don't know how to expand it to full screen. I'm a newby, so please provide somewhat detailed instrctions.

Comment: Did you isnstall the `VMWare tools`in the guest OS?

Comment: Attempting to install VMWare tools per answer below. Ran into in issue I don't know how to correct. I received an error: Unable to lock the administrative directory /var/lib/dpkg. Is another process using it? This was the first thing I ran after I launched VMWare. Is there a solution?

Comment: Sorry, been away. As per your question just wait a few minutes or restart the system and try again.

Comment: Please always provide sample text that is as close to the real thing as possible as the answers will be crafted from them.

Comment: OK, I solved my issue by altering the amount of allocated memory from 1 GB to 4 and canceling 3D in VMWare setup. Apparently the amount of video memory was insufficient to create a larger window.